# Problems in binding PouchDB doc object to v-data-table of Vuetifyjs

Tags: vuejs2, pouchdb, vuetify.js

I am trying to bind a PouchDB doc to a v-data-table component.

My HTML and JS code are here:
https://jsfiddle.net/947jbvx2/5/

When I get the data, the app throws the following errors:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "items". Expected Array, got Object.

found in

---> <VDataTable>
       <HelloWorld> at src\components\Note\NotesForm.vue
         <VContent>
           <VApp>
             <App> at src\App.vue
               <Root>
================================================================
[Vue warn]: Error in getter for watcher "someItems": "TypeError: this.items.slice is not a function"

found in

---> <VDataTable>
       <HelloWorld> at src\components\Note\NotesForm.vue
         <VContent>
           <VApp>
             <App> at src\App.vue
               <Root>
====================================================================
TypeError: this.items.slice is not a function
    at VueComponent.filteredItems (vuetify.js:7561)
    at Watcher.get (vue.common.js:3142)
 ............

===================================================================
[Vue warn]: Error in getter for watcher "everyItem": "TypeError: this.items.slice is not a function"

found in

---> <VDataTable>
       <HelloWorld> at src\components\Note\NotesForm.vue
         <VContent>
           <VApp>
             <App> at src\App.vue
               <Root>
======================================================================
TypeError: this.items.slice is not a function
    at VueComponent.filteredItems (vuetify.js:7561)
    at Watcher.get (vue.common.js:3142)
   ...................
```

Where am I going wrong? Please help.

TIA :)

Comment: The very first line seems to tell you the problem. Your code expects an array and you are getting an object.

Comment: Yes, I know.. the 'doc' (returned by PouchDB) is an array of (JSON) objects.. But even when I extract individual value from doc object and push it to 'items' array, it doesn't work as expected..

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed the issue after some trials & errors..

I pulled out the doc from pouchDB return object and pushed that to items array

```
Object.values(t).forEach(function(v) {           
           self.items.push(v.doc);
         });
```

Now the 'items' array correctly bind to v-data-table and displays records.

The modified fiddle is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/947jbvx2/7/

Thanks!